# Javascript number guesser behaving oddly with "0" values

Tags: javascript

I'm completing a JavaScript Codecademy course and am having trouble with one of the independent projects that requires you to design a number guessing game. For some reason, when "0" is involved, it returns incorrectly.

JavaScript and I aren't best friends as is, but I had a hard time with what's a relatively simple project and decided to try out one of the "challenge yourself" sections and I just can't make it work at all, or work out what's going wrong.

```
function generateTarget() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
};

function compareGuesses(userGuess, computerGuess, targetNumber) {

  function getAbsoluteDistance() {
    const uGuess = Math.abs(generateTarget() - userGuess);
    const cGuess = Math.abs(generateTarget() - computerGuess);
    return uGuess - cGuess
  };

  if (getAbsoluteDistance() <= 0) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  };
};

// 'human' is input when return is true; 'computer' when return is false

function updateScore(winner) {
  if (winner === 'human') {
    humanScore ++;
  } else if (winner === 'computer') {
    computerScore ++;
  };
};

function advanceRound() {
  currentRoundNumber +=1;
};
```

It's essentially a game where the computer generates a random "target" number, you enter a guess number and the computer generates a guess number. Depending on which guess number is closer, you or the computer wins. If you guess the same number, or your guesses are equidistant, the human is meant to win.

This is (just about) working now, except in cases when:

1. the "target" number is 0. (The computer always wins)
2. you and the computer guess the same number. (The computer always wins)
3. you and the computer guess different but equidistant numbers from the target number (The computer always wins)

I'd like to try and get my head around some basic JavaScript so I can move on to something else for a bit, but can't work out what's wrong at all or how to fix it. The only thing that I can identify that these cases have in common is the fact that there's always a "0" somewhere in the absolute distance calculation.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Please include a [example]

Comment: Where is updateScore() being called? Can you post the code on JS Fiddle or something?

Comment: One problem is that in your function getAbsoluteDistance() you are generating a new target instead of using the current one.  You need to generate one, finish the round, and then create a new target.

Comment: `userGuess` is compared to one random number. `computerGuess` is compared to a different random number, and `targetNumber` is never referenced - so, what's the point of the targetNumber, and why are the user and computer trying to guess different numbers. `compareGuesses` will return true when  the computer guess is futher or the same as the user guess (<=) - so a tie favours the computer I'm guessing

Comment: As Jaromanda X said, you have some logic errors in the calculations. *uGuess* should be `userGuess - targetNumber` and *cGuess* should be `computerGuess - targetNumber`. You don't show how the function is called.

Comment: Great -- thanks! I see what the issue is now. Sorry for the incomplete code, there's a separate codecademy js file that makes the game run properly, but it's a) quite long and b) the issue was very obviously on my end, so I just left it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of made it interactive.  From what you say the user wins in the event of a tie or when you guess the same number (a tie).  I think the comments indicated why it was failing initially, or at least what is what I see.  You were comparing to two different targets, and you can see that in a Fiddle because the results were not consistent.

```js
const userinput = document.getElementById("user");
const computerinput = document.getElementById("computer");
const targetvalue = document.getElementById("target");
const roundcount = document.getElementById("round");
var humanScore = 0;
var computerScore = 0;
var rounds = 0;

document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  targetvalue.value = generateTarget();
});

document.getElementById("calc").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

let result = compareGuesses(userinput.value, computerinput.value, targetvalue.value);

if(result) humanScore++
else computerScore++
rounds++
roundcount.innerHTML = rounds;
alert("Score:  Human:  " + humanScore + ", Computer:  " + computerScore );
});

function generateTarget() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}


function compareGuesses(userGuess, computerGuess, targetNumber) {

 const uGuess = Math.abs(targetNumber - userGuess);
  const cGuess = Math.abs(targetNumber - computerGuess);

if (uGuess - cGuess <= 0) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<input id = "user" value="" placeholder ="user">
<input id = "computer" value="" placeholder ="computer"><br>
<input id = "target" value="" placeholder ="target">
<button id ="calc" type = "submit">
Submit
</button>
<button  id ="generate" type = "submit">
Generate Number
</button><br>
Round:  <span id = "round"></span>
```

The Snippet should allow testing easily.  Did not add a thing to generate the computer guess, but that would be similar to generating a target.

Comment: Great, thanks! I see what the issue is now. Both the comments and your response were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like:

```js
function NumGuessGame(){
  this.computerScore = this.score = 0;
  this.guess = function(num){
    if(num === Math.floor(Math.random()*10)){
      this.score++;
    }
    else{
      this.computerScore++;
    }
    return this;
  }
}
var gg = new NumGuessGame;
gg.guess(9).guess(11).guess(7).guess(7);
if(gg.computerScore >= gg.score){
  console.log('Computer Wins');
}
else{
  console.log('You Win');
}
```

Of course, you should notice that the computer will almost always win under this scenario. You should notice the odds go up here:

```js
function NumGuessGame(){
  this.computerScore = this.score = 0;
  this.guess = function(num){
    if(num === Math.floor(Math.random()*10)){
      this.score++;
    }
    else{
      this.computerScore++;
    }
    return this;
  }
}
var gg = new NumGuessGame;
gg.guess(4);
if(gg.computerScore >= gg.score){
  console.log('Computer Wins');
}
else{
  console.log('You Win');
}
```

Note that the examples above expect a 0-9 guess or you lose no matter what.

Comment: A good answer should include why the OP has their issue and how your code resolves it.